# How to obtain nice font smooting? (and how to mimic Medium.com font styles?)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I did buy Charter and Kievit for my website.

The fonts are ok and are the same used by Medium.com

I use Jekyll and the smoothing is ok in most browsers but Safari.

How can I obtain a font rendering that is closer to Medium.com. Their website has settled a landmark for web fonts.

This is how my website looks:
[image]

And this is how Medium.com looks:
[image]

I detect that my website fonts are more wider, more shorter and more thicker/blurry.

This is a part of my file `fonts.css``

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Charter';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/charter.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/charter.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/charter.woff2')  format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/charter.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/charter.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Kievit';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src:url('../fonts/kievit.eot?#iefix');
  src:url('../fonts/kievit.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
  url('../fonts/kievit.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/kievit.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/kievit.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the styling applied to medium.com titles:

```
font-size: 29px;
line-height: 1.04;
letter-spacing: -.028em;
font-weight: 700;
```

And article header lines:

```
line-height: 1.5;
letter-spacing: -.004em;
font-weight: 400;
```

Pay special attention to `line-height`, `letter-spacing` and `font-weight`

Answer (score 1):

Have you inspected the elements from Medium.com?  Inspecting the **H3** of the title of the blog you've shared via Chrome Developer Tools, shows the following ccs rendered styles

```css
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
display: block;
font-family: medium-content-sans-serif-font, 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 32px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
height: 36px;
letter-spacing: -0.64px;
line-height: 36.8px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: -2px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 39px;
visibility: visible;
width: 702px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```